# Trying to create an SQLite database with tables in Ubuntu but nothing is made.

Tags: python, ubuntu, sqlite

I just got Ubuntu on me laptop, I used pip install to get to get stuff like flask, sqlite etc. I tried making code which creates a database with tables in it and populates them but it says there is nothing in the database. This much of the code works but creates no tables.

```
import sqlite3
#Connects to the list database so we can create tables and insert data.
with sqlite3.connect('/home/muba/PycharmProjects/Work/Practise.db') as connection:
    c = connection.cursor()
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(User_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName text, LastName text)""")
    c.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = on")
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Todo(todo_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, UserID INTEGER,  details,
    FOREIGN KEY(UserID) REFERENCES User(User_ID))""")
    #Code for inserting all data into tables.
```

When I add in this part

```
c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("1","Henry","Sen")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("2","Megan","Knox")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("3","Muba","Lenk")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("4","Steve","Cook")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("5","Mubasher","Khan")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("6","Jeff","Hardy")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("7","Matthew","Levine")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("8","Daniel","Potter")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("9","Chris","Sanders")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("10","Mike","Hefferson")""")

    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("1","1","Clean the kitchen")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("2","2","Finish her Sprint 1")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("3","3","Work on all remaining Assignments")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("4","3","Document all his assignments")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("5","4","Starting studying for his exams")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("6","5","Clean his bedroom")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("7","6","Take the dog for a walk.")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("8","7","Go out and see the sun for the first time")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("9","8","Practise for upcoming soccer game")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("10","9","Catch the bus on time")""")
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO todo(todo_ID, UserID, details) Values("11","10","Go grocery shopping")""")
```

it gives me this error.

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/muba/PycharmProjects/Work/Database.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/muba/PycharmProjects/Work/Database.py", line 12, in <module>
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO User (User_ID, FirstName,LastName) values("1","Henry","Sen")""")
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: User.User_ID
```

I'm not sure what i did wrong, when i did it in windows before it worked fine. I'm not sure if i missed something like if i have to mention primary keys on or something >_<

Answer (score 0):

It should run fine first time.

But if you run it more than once, trying to add User with same id causes the exception.

If you want to add new item only, check whether there's item with the id.

```
c.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE User_ID = "1"')
if c.fetchone()[0] == 0:
    c.execute('INSERT ...')
```

If you want to start from zero, delete records before inserts:

```
c.execute('DELETE FROM User')
c.execute('DELETE FROM todo')
```

Comment: that makes sense but even if i get that error, shouldn't i still be able to view the tables that I have created?

Comment: It doesn't look like you called `commit()` to make your changes persistent.

Comment: Ohh, I'm such an idiot>_< I was in the wrong folder trying to get the database >_<

Comment: @tony, How did you check the database? Try `sqlite3 /home/muba/PycharmProjects/Work/Practise.db`, then `.tables`. What do you get?

Comment: I figured it out. I just clicked on database properties to see if it had anything in it and it had some data which i assumed meant the tables.

Comment: oh yes it is. I had a minor mistake in the path that i entered.